# How to parse a string by certain pattern and tokenize the result to the dictionary?

Tags: c#

I have a string like following:

```
Column1 LIKE 'value1%' AND Column2 LIKE 'value2%' ... ColumnN LIKE 'valueN%'
```

I need to tokenize the string to a dictionary like

```
'Column1', 'value1'
'Column2', 'value2'
...
'ColumnN', 'valueN'
```

How do I combine regex and linq to parse the string and get the result dictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that you can do this with LINQ, just splitting the string appropriately:

```
str.Split(new string[]{" AND "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
   .Select(likeClause => likeClause.Split(new string[]{" LIKE "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
   .ToDictionary(a => a[0], a => a[1].Trim(new char[]{'\'', '%'}))
```

Comment: Will it get rid of `'` and `%` from values to get result as described in question?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, sorry, didn't pay enough attention to that. Edited.

Comment: I have a complier error at the str.split(" AND ") saying it has invalid arguments

Comment: @GLP, I always forget that there is no such overload for String.Split. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex with out linq  as well with no split

```
    static string test = @"Column1 LIKE 'value1%' AND Column2 LIKE 'value2%'";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string,string>(); 

        foreach (Match m in  Regex.Matches(test,@"(^|AND\s*)(\w*).*?LIKE.*?\'(.*?)%"))
        {
            dict.Add(m.Groups[2].Value, m.Groups[3].Value);
        }
    }
```